# How to implement a modal form that can be used throughout entire Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, modal-dialog

I'd like to implement a modal form, such as an unobtrusive login or feedback form, that can be accessed from anywhere in the application. Being that an instance variable has to be passed to the view, how could one best achieve this in a manner that is consistent with Rails' principles? I'm thinking of rendering a new.html.erb view (or partial) in the main application layout with a display set to none and then manipulating it was javascript.